# View Spark UI for Jobs executed via Azure ADF

Tags: permissions, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, spark-ui

I am not able to view the spark-ui for databricks jobs executed through notebook activity in Azure datafactory.

Does anyone know which permissions needs to be added to enable the same?

[image]

Comment: What do you have in the notebook

Comment: Notebook has spark scala code.

Comment: Please check updated configuration requirement in answer, it should work now, I tested 

Answer (score 0):

### --Update

Ensure you have [Cluster-level permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/access-control/cluster-acl#cluster-level-permissions) on PROD env

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Job permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/access-control/jobs-acl#job-permissions)

> There are five permission levels for jobs: No Permissions, Can View,
> Can Manage Run, Is Owner, and Can Manage. Admins are granted the Can
> Manage permission by default, and they can assign that permission to
> non-admin users.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Next...

Am able to view the completed jobs in the Spark UI without any additional setup.

[image]

[image]

It maybe that the stuff you are doing in the Notebook, does not constitute for a Spark Job.

Refer: [Web UI](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/web-ui.html) and [Monitoring and Instrumentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) for more details.

Checkout [Spark Glossary](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html#glossary)

> **Note:** Job A parallel computation consisting of multiple tasks that gets spawned in response to a Spark action (e.g. save, collect);
> you'll see this term used in the driver's logs.

[View cluster information in the Apache Spark UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/clusters-manage#--view-cluster-information-in-the-apache-spark-ui)

> You can get details about active and terminated clusters. If you
> restart a terminated cluster, the Spark UI displays information for
> the restarted cluster, not the historical information for the
> terminated cluster.

So, If I run a notebook with a task to simply display my mounts or with a task that failed or exception, it is not listed in Spark UI.

[image]

[image]

**#job/83** is not seen

[image]

Comment: this is disabled for me in prod due to some permissions. We can view the same in dev env.

Comment: Can you share snips of both and access you have on them now. Are you able to view Spark UI in cluster but not jobs listed ?

Comment: Have added the screenshot to question. If access in databricks for cluster is given, then we are able to view the same. we dont need complete access. Is there any specific permission / action that can be assigned to the Azure role to view the same.

Comment: oki, you would have to ask the admin in prod to configure job permissions. Since you seem to already have cluster permission